# Perl - What does grep function with -P arg specify?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I'm looking at code that has the following syntax:

```
@match = grep {/$sometext/-iP} @$myarray;
```

I know that -i finds a match ignoring case. What does the "P" specify?

Comment: The code you have posted seems incorrect. You cannot have a dash `-` in the modifiers to a regex, so that statement would be interpreted as a subtraction, and `iP` would be interpreted as a subroutine. Add `use warnings` to your script, there should be quite a lot of warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is incorrect.  Probably the author confused Perl's built-in `grep` function with the `grep`  command-line tool.

In [GNU `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/index.html), the `-i` option causes it to match case-insensitively, and `-P` tells it to use Perl-style regular expressions.

In Perl, this:

```
@match = grep {/$sometext/-iP} @$myarray;
```

is almost certainly incorrect (though as TLP points out in a comment, it *could* be interpreted so that the `-` is subtraction and `iP` is a function call).

Perl regular expression are already Perl-style, so the `P` is unnecessary.

Probably what was intended was something like:

```
@match = grep { /$sometext/i } @$myarray;
```

or, more simply:

```
@match = grep /$sometext/i, @$myarray;
```

Note that the `i` qualifier applies to the pattern match `/$sometext/`, *not* to the `grep`.
See [`perldoc -f grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) for more information on the `grep` function.